# Why svg text is unselectable?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to make selectable tooltip in D3.js

here is code:

```
var tooltip = obj.svg
  .append('g')
  .append('text')
  .attr("id", "tooltip")
  .text( "SPICE")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .style("opacity", .0);
```

...

```
.on("click", function (d) {
        d3.selectAll("#tooltip").transition()
        .style("opacity", (obj.tooltipVisible && obj.tooltipId === d.id) ? 0.0 : 1)
```

And in browser as a result I have following element  (I have no any css for it either):

```
<g><text id="tooltip" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="red" x="35" y="11.538461538490488" style="opacity: 1;">SPICE</text></g>
```

And the problem is that this text is unselectable, through pointer changes on text hovering.

So how to make this text element selectable by mouse?

If it makes sense - whole svg picture is here - you can see word SPICE on the top left, it's unselectable, I suppose text on the background prevents current text selection:
[image]

Comment: It's selectable for me although you can't see it being selected if opacity:0. If this is the issue try `fill:rgba(255,0,0,0)` instead of `opacity:0`

Comment: @enxaneta Opacity is fine, tooltip is invisible until element is clicked. But when clicked and visible - the problem appears, I've tried in several browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem selecting this text, but the location of the `g` is probably inside a translated `g`.

Do you have some kind of overlay on the graph?

Make a very simple example like this.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
<g><text id="tooltip" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" fill="red" x="35" y="11.538461538490488" style="opacity: 1;">SPICE</text></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found out at least the reason of the problem - the svg and even html is fine - in html viewer it's selectable. But in my program it is react application, so it figures out - react prevents selection, still don't know how to fix it, but the reason is found.